# Rx.ReplaySubject subscription callback not being called

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an rxjs ReplaySubject that will either emit a value or null depending on what environment I am on.  Meaning if in a certain environment I make a service call and get the data.  If I am not in that environment I just call next(null) on the replay subject.  In the component where I subscribe to this all works fine if the service call was made.  If I had done next(null) then my callback is never fired.

My assumption is that the null value will not be returned because it was set before I subscribed but I thought that was the entire point of ReplaySubject. I have googled then until I ran out of different ways to explain the issue and all I get is the read me file for ReplaySubject.  Hoping somebody can tell me what I am doing wrong.  I thought maybe it was because I passed in null so I passed in "Hello" instead and still nothing.  Here is a code sample:

```
public Data = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
init(){
 if(!window.Something){
   //subscribe callback is never fired in this case.
   this.Data.next(null);
 }else{
    this.http.get(...).map(...{
     //this works 
     this.Data.next(result);
    });
 }}
```

The mistake I made actually had nothing to do with Rx.  I can't remember exactly but it was making so the condition was never true.  This kept the code from executing.

Comment: is the http subscribed to?

Comment: **if(!window.Something)** are you sure that this condition passed in your case

Comment: @suraj Yes.  The http part is actually working.  It is the first part of the if that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.next(null)` on any Observable is correct. Everything is a value in RxJS including `null` and `undefined`. So the problem is probably somewhere else than this.

This is what you're doing right now and it both cases (when you uncomment the second `if`) it works as should. The value is stored in the `ReplaySubject` and then replayed or pushed directly to the current observer:

```
let subject = new ReplaySubject(1);

// if (!window.document) {
if (!window.whatever) {
  subject.next(null);
} else {
  setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next('Hello');
  }, 500);
}

subject.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/cigocak/edit?js,console

Comment: ok.  I will keep looking.  I would expect the first part of if to work since the else does but I am currently at a loss.  thanks.

Comment: And it was a stupid mistake on my part.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Jason would you mind updating your question with your mistake pls?